# Editor with a TeX-aware spellchecker

Tags: editors, spelling

Is there around a TeX editor with a spellchecker that recognizes and handles properly TeX commands? For instance, I'd like it to underline with a red wavy line if I write "ntheorem" in my text, but not `\usepackage{ntheorem}`, figuring out automatically that the argument of `usepackage` is not meant to be a word but a "special command". Similarly, it should ignore most mathematical content (but not that inside `\[ \text{} \]`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual, emacs in combination with auctex and any flyspell is quite good in this. It recognizes many TeX-like constructs and even finds out which babel-options you have in your source file. So if you specify babel or the documentclass with a language option, emacs tries to make the spell checking accordingly. For me, this does not leave open any wishes :)

Comment: You might also want to customize the `ispell-tex-skip-alists` variable.